# Dynamic name use for workbook reference

Tags: excel, vba

at the moment when i use this code and switch to another workbook it will give an error, i was told to use Workbook reference before the .Sheets, the only problem now is, the workbook name is dynamic.
the name of the workbook is set in cell C11 , but it also need to have the XLSM extetion behind it.
simple explanation
i was thinking about something like this

```
Workbook("C11+.XLSM").Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").
```

this the code using right now:

```
    Private Sub ExcelStopWatchCobalt()
    If Range("c13").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in Machine quantity"
      End If
  .Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value = Format(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "hh:mm:ss")
    NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B3") And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value <= Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B4") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With
        
    Else
        If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B4") And Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value <= Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B5") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
        
    Else
        If Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("a1").Value > Sheets("CalculationsCobalt").Range("B5") Then
        With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    End If
    End If
    End If
    
    
    Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelStopWatchCobalt"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CalculationsCobalt")` if you mean the workbook the code is written in.

Comment: `the workbook name is dynamic. the name of the workbook is set in cell C11` How are you opening this workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the structure of your code all but prevents an easy solution, aided by missing variable declarations. Here is an alternative design.

```
Option Explicit

Public t                    As Double
Public PreviousTimerValue   As Double

Sub CallingProcedure()
    ' 279
    
    Dim Wb      As Workbook
    Dim Fn      As String               ' workbook name
    Dim Targets As Variant              ' differentiators

    
    With ActiveSheet                    ' better to call the sheet by name
        If .Cells(13, "C").Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in Machine quantity"
        Else
            ' the smallest value last and 1000 must be much larger than you ever expect
            Targets = Array(1000, .Cells(5, "B").Value, .Cells(4, "B").Value, .Cells(3, "B").Value)
            Fn = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, "C").Value & ".xlsm"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Wb = Workbooks(Fn)
            If Err.Number Then
                MsgBox "The workbook """ & Fn & """ isn't open.", _
                       vbInformation, "Can't access source data"
            Else
                ExcelStopWatchCobalt Wb, Targets
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelStopWatchCobalt(Wb As Workbook, _
                                 Targets As Variant)
    ' 279
    
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim Col         As Long
    Dim NextTick    As Double
    
    With Wb.Worksheets("CalculationsCobalt").Cells(1, 1)
        ' .Value = Format(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "hh:mm:ss")
        ' consider this instead:-
        .Value = Time - t + PreviousTimerValue  ' preserve the true numeric value for onward use
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"              ' display the value as a string
        
        Col = Application.Match(.Value, Targets, -1)
        Col = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(0, 255, 0), vbWhite)(Col - 1)
    End With
    
    StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Col
    NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelStopWatchCobalt"
End Sub
```

Starting from the top, the two public variables `t` and `PreviousTimerValue` are presumed to be declared by you (or should have been declared). They support your design of the timer operation with which I didn't want to interfere.

My `CallingProcedure` may, in fact, be a part of an existing procedure in your project. It's point here is twofold. One, it is the only part of the code that refers to the ActiveSheet, which is in `ThisWorkbook`, which I presume to be not the one in which the *CalculationsCobalt* worksheet resides. The way I understood your project, the ActiveSheet contains the workbook name and B3:B5, B11, and B13 but not A1. Two, this procedure separates everything that is ***not*** in ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet and therefore in the other, changing workbook's *CalculationsCobalt* worksheet.

Accordingly, everything to be taken from the ActiveSheet is read in the `CallingProcedure` and passed to the `ExcelStopWatchCobalt` procedure as argument. This second procedures does ***not*** refereence the ActiveSheet but squarely and exclusively faces the "CalculationsCobalt" worksheet from various other workbooks.

There is a known flaw in this line of code. `Targets = Array(1000, .Cells(5, "B").Value, .Cells(4, "B").Value, .Cells(3, "B").Value)`. The MATCH function requires a limit, expressed in your code as >B5. B5 is a time and therefore a value below 1. 1000 is bigger than 1. But your code inserts `Now`, which is a Date/Time value and therefore much larger than 1000. You may modify the array to have 100000 as its highest value.

Similarly, `Col = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(0, 255, 0), vbWhite)`. You must specify a colour that your shape should assume if none of the colours in your code is applied. My array specifies vbWhite. The whole colour selection replaces your multiple IFs with an INDEX/MATCH function. I'm explaining the two arrays here - the first being the MATCH, the second the INDEX - so that you might reconstruct them in your worksheet for testing.

My code isn't tested in context, meaning I tested the parts but can't know if they will work the same way in your project.